# Numpy concatenating multiple axes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am not sure why I can not concatenate multiple dimensions of an array together using the the numpy.concatenate function. For example:

```
    array_2d.shape = [1200,1200]
    array2_2d.shape = [1200,1200]
    final_array1 = numpy.concatenate((array_2d,array2_2d),axes=0) # shape = (2400,1200)
    final_array2 = numpy.concatenate((array_2d,array2_2d),axes=1) # shape = (1200,2400)
```

Is there a way I can get the 2 arrays to concatenate both axes to yield a shape of (2400,2400)? Or am I just thinking of this approach incorrectly with the concatenation of arrays? Some help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: Take a look to http://www.python-course.eu/numpy.php

Comment: I am confused by these words "concatenate multiple dimensions of an array together".

Comment: You are trying to stick two square blocks together to make a bigger square block. This will not work; you aren't putting together enough blocks to make the big block you want.

Comment: Show us with small arrays (e.g. (2,3) size)) what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should use numpy.tile(). Read [this link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for more information.

example:

```
a = np.array(([1,2],[3,4]))
b = np.tile(a, (2,2))
```

will create a 4x4 array from a 2x2 array, by repeating both axis.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what you're trying to accomplish, let's call array1 A, and array2 B, and some unknown array as X. Like you said, the following is 2400 x 1200:

```
 | A |
 | B |
```

But this would be a 2400 by 2400 array:

```
 | A | X |
 | X | B |
```

and so would this:

```
 | A | X |
 | B | X |
```

and this...:

```
 | A | A |
 | B | B |
```

The real question is how many times you want to concatenate each array and in which dimension or if you want to zero pad:

```
 | A | 0 |
 | 0 | B |
```

Which would be accomplished by using numpy to create an array of zeros and concatenating in the appropriate direction on both A and B before concatenating the results together.